# MySQL error while trying to "translate" MsSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create two tables on a MySQL database, with the same characteristics of its MsSQL version but i get a syntax error. Any suggestions please?

```
CREATE TABLE logins 
             ( 
                          `id` INT auto_increment NOT NULL, 
                          `name` CHAR (10) NOT NULL, 
                          `pw` CHAR (10) NOT NULL, 
                          `email` VARCHAR (50) NULL, 
                          `role`  INT DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL, 
                          CONSTRAINT `pk_logins` PRIMARY KEY (`id` ASC) 
             );

CREATE TABLE locations 
             ( 
                          `lat`   DECIMAL (10, 6) DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL, 
                          `lon`   DECIMAL (10, 6) DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL, 
                          `dt`    DATETIME NULL, 
                          `id`    INT auto_increment NOT NULL, 
                          `owner` INT NULL 
             );
```

EDIT: The error i get is

```
SQL query:


CREATE TABLE logins 
             ( 
                          `id` INT auto_increment NOT NULL, 
                          `name` CHAR (10) NOT NULL, 
                          `pw` CHAR (10) NOT NULL, 
                          `email` VARCHAR (50) NULL, 
                          `role`  INT DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL, 
                          CONSTRAINT `pk_logins` PRIMARY KEY (`id` ASC) 
             )
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '((1)) NOT NULL, 
                          CONSTRAINT `pk_logins` PRIMARY KEY (' at line 7
```

Comment: Your question may be downvoted. You didn't provide any information about the said syntax error. Pls do so before you can expect an answer to your question

Comment: Editing now. Thanks.

Comment: @Lion ... edited the question.

Comment: @KoukouRoukou you wrap the default value with two brackets: `((0))` Seems like one bracket pair works. Try to reduce them to one or remove both of them like this: `role  INT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
CREATE TABLE logins 
             ( 
                          `id` INT auto_increment NOT NULL, 
                          `name` CHAR (10) NOT NULL, 
                          `pw` CHAR (10) NOT NULL, 
                          `email` VARCHAR (50) NULL, 
                          `role`  INT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL, 
                          PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
             );

CREATE TABLE locations 
             ( 
                          `lat`   DECIMAL (10, 6) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
                          `lon`   DECIMAL (10, 6) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
                          `dt`    DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, 
                          `id`    INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
                          `owner` INT ,
                          PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
             );
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'autoincrement NOT NULL, 
                          `owner` INT  
             ' at line 6

Comment: Sorry, try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE logins 
         ( 
                      `id` INT auto_increment NOT NULL, 
                      `name` CHAR (10) NOT NULL, 
                      `pw` CHAR (10) NOT NULL, 
                      `email` VARCHAR (50) NULL, 
                      `role`  INT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL, 
                      CONSTRAINT `pk_logins` PRIMARY KEY (`id` ASC) 
         )
```